# How to recognize the escape Characters at the time of Splitting the String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the String value of `"Hello,World\\,,1,2,3"` and I need it to be Splitted with the delimiter of `,`. However, the method also needs to recognize the escpace characters as well at the time of splitting and eventually the output needs to be an array like,

```
[Hello, World,, 1, 2, 3]
```

I have a method to do it but it doesn't  recognize the escape characters though. Its provided below,

```
public static String[] tokenize1(String record, char delimiter) {

        String delim = String.valueOf(delimiter);
        String[] arr = record.split(delim);

        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: _"I have a method to do it "_ -- SHOW what you have already done

Comment: No, I meant the method that splits the `String`, I can do the same with various ways like `StringTokenizer` etc, but, still cant recognize theescape characters

Comment: If the string you are splitting actually has escaped characters, I would say there is a smell here.  Why does your string have those escape characters, and what is its source?

Comment: `[Hello, World,, 1, 2, 3]` is not an array of strings. Therefore, your method can not return such an object.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen then you need to make sure they won't ask these questions in the tech interview

Comment: What is the actual string?  Can you declare a string variable, assign something to it, and then do a `println` to show us what it actually contains?  I think there is a simple answer here, but I won't speculate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The String is `"Hello,World\\,,1,2,3"` and provided in the beginning of the question

Comment: So you're saying the raw string has _two_ backslashses escaping the comma?  That's really strange to me, it should only have one backslash.  This is why I'm asking you these questions.

Comment: Yes, it will need to split based on the delimiter which is in this case `,` but  need not to do it when there is an escape character like `\\`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The second is necessary for Java string escaping.

Comment: @AAA Is it also a requirement to remove the backslash from the result?

Comment: @shmosel   Yes, I suggest to read the question carefully

Comment: @shmosel Do you get my question?  If he wants two literal backslashes for Java then he needs _four_ in the string.

Comment: @AAA I wouldn't have asked if I wasn't reading carefully. Your output doesn't contain a backslash, but nowhere do you mention its removal as a requirement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, the raw string has 1 backslash, which translates to 2 in Java.

Comment: @shmosel But is that Java code or an actual string in a file?  This is the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's Java code, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try splitting on comma but with a negative lookbehind which asserts that the comma has not been escaped by a backslash:

```
String input = "Hello,World\\,,1,2,3";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<!\\\\),");
for (String part : parts) {
    // uncomment to also remove backslash
    // part = part.replaceAll("\\\\,", ",");
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
World\,
1
2
3
```

### Demo

Comment: Then I guess removing the backlash wasn't a requirement.

Comment: @shmosel I also was not sure of this.  It seems to me the OP wants to split by comma while preserving the escape.  Anyway, I updated with an option to unescape retained commas.

Comment: Minor nitpick: I would go with `String.replace()` and avoid the quadruple backslash.